# MYSQL Join relationship

Tags: php, mysql

I dont know how to make this with JOIN but:

I have a post table with 4 columns:
- ID
- Name
- Content
- id_createur

I store id of creator and this is the users table:

- ID
- pseudo
- firstname
- lastname
- email
- password

Ok, now i want to get all the post, off course i make:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
```

And after a while in PHP:

```
<?php while($a = $articles->fetch()) { ?>
<li><a href="article.php?id=<?= $a['id'] ?>"><?= $a['name'] ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

But i want to show in my while, the firstname and the lastname of the owner of the post.

I dont know by relationship when i can make this...

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Probably `SELECT * FROM posts as p join users as u on p.id_createur = u.id` will give you a starting point. Replace the `*` with the columns you actually want, and uses the aliases otherwise you'll get an ambiguous error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT p.ID as postid, p.name as postname, 
       u.firstname username, u.lastname as userlastname 
FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN users u 
ON posts.id_createur = users.ID`
```

and get the users data related to each post as `$a['postid']`, `$a['postname']`, `$a['username'`], `$a['userlastname'`].

Comment: Edited according to @user3783243 comment